# Need a conversion from Jquery to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having issues transforming this from JQuery to javascript. I have tried the document.getElementbyClassName("tile").style.left = x * tileWidth + tileDepth * z + tileOffsetLeft + "px". But it doesn't like that and gives me the error Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'left').

```
export function createTiles() {
    for (let counter = 0; counter < coordinates.length; counter++) {
        const coord = coordinates[counter];
        const [x,y,z] = coord;
        const image = images[counter];

        const tile = $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("tile")
            .css({
                left: x * tileWidth + tileDepth * z + tileOffsetLeft + "px",
                top: y * tileHeight + tileDepth * z + tileOffsetTop + "px",
                zIndex: z
            });
        const tileFront = $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("tileFront")
            .css({
                width: tileWidth + "px",
                height: tileHeight + "px",
                borderRadius: tileRoundness + "px"
            })
            .append(image);
        tile.append(tileFront).appendTo("#game");        
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't like it because it should be [`getElementsbyClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). And `getElementsbyClassName` returns a node list that you can't directly apply a style to - you'd need to iterate over the node list and apply the style to each node.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
 .addClass("tileFront")
```

to

```
 .classList.add("tileFront")`
```

Comment: This only answers part of the problem.